# How is the expression for the Stress-energy tensor in Cosmology a covariant expression?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, cosmology, universe, covariance

Consider the energy-momentum tensor $$T_{\mu\nu}=(p+\rho)u_\mu u_\nu+pg_{\mu\nu}$$ used in Cosmology. I have a problem with this equation. Since this a tensor equation the RHS should transform in the same manner as the LHS. The LHS transforms as a rank-2 tenor under Lorentz transformation and so does $u_\nu u_\nu$ and $g_{\mu\nu}$. But $\rho+p$ or $p$ doesn't transform as a Lorentz scalar.

How can then that the both sides transform in the same manner?

Comment: $\rho$ and $p$ are numbers. Why shouldn't they transform as scalars? They are the energy density and pressure measured in a local rest frame.

Comment: @FrodCube $\rho$ is the $0^{th}$ component of $j^\mu$, and it doesn't transform as a Lorentz scalar. Of course, it is a scalar under rotation.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, $p$ and $\rho$ are components of the energy momentum tensor measured in a specific frame: the comoving frame, so yhey are invariant by definition. It's just like the proper time of a particle: is the time as measured in its rest frame, and by definition it has that same value in every frame.

Comment: You meant since $c^2\rho^2-\textbf{j}^2=j_\mu j^\mu=\text{Lorentz invariant}$, in the rest frame where $\textbf{j}=0$, $c^2\rho^{\prime 2}=\text{Lorentz invariant}$. It is the $\rho^\prime$ that appears in $T^{\mu\nu}$. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Don't think too hard about transformation laws. If you want to calculate $\rho$ in some frame, you do the following: go to the rest frame, and calculate $\rho$ there. It doesn't matter in what frame you are, $\rho$ **by definition** is its value in the rest frame.

Comment: $c\rho$ is the zeroth component of $j^\mu$, and therefore changes from one inertial frame to another. However, the in rest frame of the particle $j_\mu j^\mu(\textbf{j}=0)=c^2\rho^{\prime 2}$ like $p_\mu p^\mu(\textbf{p}=0)=m^2c^4$. Therefore, the numerical values of the Lorentz invariant quantities (contractions), in this case, are values of their zeroth component in the rest frame of the particle. Do you understand my comment now?@Javier

Comment: @SRS: This is true for $\rho$, not so much for $p$, because it's not the zero component of anything; it's the $i-i$ component of $T_{\mu\nu}$.